# Mobile images slider

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I want to do a mobile webpage, which in the middle of the webpage, I will be able to swipe my finger to the left/right and scroll between images there.

a photo to demonstrate:

[image: Demonstration]
I wanna be able to swipe between the censored images with my finger.
How do I do such a thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a cover-flow like thing. This might guide you in the proper direction : http://andrebrov.net/dev/carousel/

Source Link : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-carousel-widget

GITHUB Link : https://github.com/andrebrov/jqm.carousel

Here's how the HTML would look like :

```
<div style="height:460px;width:300px;">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
      <div id="carousel_scrollpane" class="carousel-content">
        <div id="carousel_content" class="carousel-content-scroller"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="carousel_nav" class="carousel-nav">
        <div id="carousel_mid" class="carousel-mid"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then, the initialisation would go this way :

```
var carousel = new $.widgets.Carousel({
    uuid: "carousel",
    args: {
        "scrollInterval": 600,
        "itemWidth": 290
    },
    value: [{
        "title": "Tron.Legacy",
        "image": "images/1.jpg"
    }, {
        "title": "Yogi Bear",
        "image": "images/2.jpg"
    }, {
        "title": "The Chronicles of Narnia: The Voyage of the Dawn Treader",
        "image": "images/3.jpg"
    }, {
        "title": "The Fighter",
        "image": "images/4.jpg"
    }, {
        "title": "Tangled",
        "image": "images/5.jpg"
    }]
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is getting very close to what I need :)
Can't this thing show the current image in the middle and a little bit of the next images so people will actually notice that they can swipe to see more images?

***Q*** :How do I create a mobile simulator on my PC?

Comment: u cant create a mobile simulator on your pc. even if u, ul jus end up setting up an iframe with width and height to mobile systems. you could use jsfiddle though. if u become a member they let u debug ur code in ur pc **while** viewing the ui in the mobile. pretty slick, id say. One more option would be use Chrom dev-tools useragent..